# Searching for E-mails with Exchange Web Services Operations

Tags: web-services, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am doing an integration project for a customer running Microsoft Exchange 2007 (BPOS). I am looking for a way to search for e-mail using the Exchange Web Services Operations -- MS' API to their own hosted exchange solution. So far, I have found a nice API description, but as far as I can see none of it allows for searching for e-mails using different criteria. In this case, I need to find all e-mails that contains a specific sender or recipient identified by an e-mail address.

Could you provide me with guidance on how to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my (admittedly minimal) experience with Exchange Web Services, the only way to do this would be to retrieve all items in a folder and scan through their properties.

You need to specify which properties are retrieved when you call the FindItem() operation.

```
PathToUnindexedFieldType fieldTypePath = new PathToUnindexedFieldType();
fieldTypePath.FieldURI = UnindexedFieldURIType.folderDisplayName;

GetFolderType folderType = new GetFolderType();
folderType.FolderShape = new FolderResponseShapeType();
folderType.FolderShape.BaseShape = DefaultShapeNamesType.IdOnly;
folderType.FolderShape.AdditionalProperties = new BasePathToElementType[1];
folderType.FolderShape.AdditionalProperties[0] = fieldTypePath;
```

So the only saving grace is that you don't need to retrieve the full email body etc - just the fields you explicitly require.